# Oozie Coordinator config properties

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have an Oozie coordinator which calls a specific Oozie workflow.

In order to invoke this coordinator, I need to provide the workflow with all the config properties it requires. Does this mean I should be duplicating all the config properties that belong in the workflow's `job.properties` file and putting them in the `coordinator.properties` file as well? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Did you find the answer yet?

Answer (score 1):

The only properties file that is loaded by Oozie is the one that you provide when you call the Oozie command line tool, so yes you will need to have the properties applicable to the workflow included in the properties file that you provide when starting your coordinator.

Answer (score 0):

Being new to the whole Hadoop environment and learning as I go I would just like to add a bit of further clarification for others like me to save them time searching

When you just have a workflow the Oozie job is started with the Workflows properties file
When you have a coordinator which calls the workflow then the coordinators properties file is used ( the workflow's properties file is ignored)
When you have a bundle job which calls one or more coordinators (which in turn call the workflows) then the bundle's properties file is used (the coordinators and workflows properties files are ignored)

Further to this as mentioned previously the properties file name mentioned in the oozie command is what is used

Hope this clarifies things a bit more